# VSCode Integrated Terminal does not work in elementary OS Juno

Tags: vscode, zsh

[image]

I can't use vscode intergrated terminal in my elementary OS. I use zsh shell with powerlevel10k theme.

Comment: Works fine in VSCodium with bash for me. Try switching back to bash and test. If that works, it's probably VSCode related, not elementary related.

Comment: I am using VScode not vscodium.

Comment: VSCodium is literally VSCode, but de-microsoft'd, so unless it's related to Microsoft telemetry, I doubt it matters (which would also STILL make it a VSCode issue ;)). Did you actually even TRY the recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems using zsh on VSCode too. Following these steps here [from  Farhan Madani](https://dev.to/webdevfarhan/comment/fdd5) kinda solve my problem, as you can see...

[image: VSCode terminal with zsh and PowerLevel10K]

These fonts are not entirely perfect (don't know why yet), but do the work.

In addition, I've just been reading the powerlevel10K instructions again with more attention, and found their [font recomendation](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#manual-font-installation). After install all fonts they recommend it seems more ok now. Some icons seem to be less cut, but I think it is better now.

[image: VSCode terminal with zsh and powerlevel10K font recommendations]